# Explained variance in dimensionality reduction

Tags: pca, feature-selection, dimensionality-reduction, nonlinear

I am new to dimensionality reduction and I am trying to learn different techniques about it. I am noticing that, unlike PCA, many other algorithms do not provide the explained variance of each feature (or am I wrong?). That said, how do I choose the size of the reduced feature?

I would appreciate also some reference to read about the state-of-the-art algorithms for nonlinear dimensionality reduction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose your input is $X_{m \times d}$, where $m$ is the number of data points and $d$ is the dimension of each point.  The total variance is a property of your input $X$; call it $v(X)$.

Now, suppose the reconstructed input after applying dimensionality reduction is $\tilde{X}$ (of the same dimensions), it has a variance $v(\tilde{X})$.

Then the fraction of variance explained is simply: $v(\tilde{X})/v(X)$.

This doesn't depend on how you implement the dimensionality reduction.  For PCA, the explained variance can be computed directly from the eigenvalues of the covariance matrix.  For other non-linear techniques, you can compute the reconstruction and then compute the explained variance from its intuitive definition.

Comment: When I try it with PCA I get completely different results. In my case I have 14 features and using the eigenvalues I get that the first 5 are sufficient to explain all the variance. Doing what you suggested I get that only the first 2 are needed.

Comment: Could you post your matrix (if it's small), its eigenvalues and the list of explained_variance_ratio output by your PCA algorithm?

Comment: My bad. I forgot that Matlab automatically centers and standardize the input data. Doing as you said returns the same result as using the eigenvalues. Thanks!